# Detect when "back to app" is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-location

I've created a function which is suppose to handle the permission with location, so that the app will close if it does not have permission to location. However when you press open settings and press "back to app" in the status bar the `determeinePermission` method is not being executed again. I've tried to add it to `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear`. what can I do?

```
func determinePermission() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

    case .Authorized:
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.delegate = self
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }


    case .NotDetermined:
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .AuthorizedWhenInUse, .Restricted, .Denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Background Location Access Disabled",
            message: "In order to be notified about adorable kittens near you, please open this app's settings and set location access to 'Always'.",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
            exit(0)
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .Default) { (action) in
            if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(openAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding it to appDidBecameActive. P.S. you can't close an app programtically which is what you say you want to do. Putting exit(0) in your code is not permitted.

Comment: well okay i'll find a solution for that :) but the issue is calling a method when pressing back to

Comment: Did you try it with appDidBecomeActive?

Comment: It worked please make a answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding it to `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: it is applicationDidBecomeActive not 'add'

Comment: UIApplicationDidDidBecomeActive will also trigger after temporary interruptions like phone calls or SMS messages, so I would recommend UIApplicationDidEnterForeground instead.